# Android, control the volume of a background sound

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

How can I control the volume of a background sound?

I'm making a game, and in some states I want to increase or decrease the background sound.

I have tried some things with MediaPlayer and SoundPool, but it did't do what I wanted.

I dont want to change the phone volume, but the volume of the sound. Is this possible? If yes how?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told use what *"some things with `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool`"* means, or shown us any code, so it's hard to say exactly what the problem might be.

If you want to make the volume keys modify the volume of your app's music rather than the voice call volume, you might be missing a call to [`setVolumeControlStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream(int)) (e.g. `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`).
Refer to ["Controlling Your App’s Volume and Playback"](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html) in the Android developer documentation for more information.

If you're using the `MediaPlayer` `setVolume` method, then keep in mind that the maximum volume you can set is `1.0` (i.e. the original volume of the audio data you're playing).